# How to retrieve or definitely delete leaderboard in Google Games?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, leaderboard

How to retrieve deleted leaderboard in Google Games.
We have created and published an Android Game in Developer Console. After a while it turned out that the two leaderboards are not necessary and have been removed.

But Google still shows deleted leaderboards in your Google Games Android App.

Now we want to restore deleted leaderboard and use them again, but we can't find them even though they are available in the Google Games Android App.

We don't see those leaderboards in Developers Console and APIS Console.

The question is as follows.
You can restore deleted leaderboards?
Is it possible to permanently delete the leaderboards including these in  Google Games Android App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing unnecessary Leaderboards from developer console and Google Services (Settings > Aplication > Google services > clear application data), Google removed all Leaderboards have disappeared. This means that all new users using the application, you will not see the old Leaderboards.