# Google Play Games Services Console not showing project

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play

I published 2 apps, both of which had Google Play Games Services integration. I tested the leaderboards and they worked.

Later, users found that the leaderboards weren't working. I checked, they weren't. I went to the dev. console and went to the Google Play Games section and I saw that all of my projects **vanished**. None showed.

I tried to recreate a project for one of the apps, but when I did the "Link an app" part of the setup, I got an error saying:

> "Client ID is globally unique and already in use."

What can I do to get my projects showing in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you did not save the leaderboard in the developer console ( or you deleted it by mistake) but the api console is remembering the client id.

This might help:

[This client ID is globally unique and is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087260/this-client-id-is-globally-unique-and-is-already-in-use)

Comment: Thanks. What could I do about this. Can I get the leaderboards back?

Comment: I don't think you can get them back (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591055/how-to-retrieve-or-definitely-delete-leaderboard-in-google-games), but you could try Shygar's appraoch in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087260/this-client-id-is-globally-unique-and-is-already-in-use).