# Disable android application leaderboard

Tags: android, eclipse, game-center-leaderboard

I'm working in android application using eclipse and I have a big problem with the leader-board.

How can I disable it or hide the leader-board?

Comment: Uhm... You manually have to start the leader-board using an `Intent`. What prevents you from leaving out that line?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand i'm beginner in android development i'm trying to reskin an android app in eclipse and i'm stuck hiding leaderboard service

Comment: If you don't know how to *remove* a button, you should probably start with an easy "hello world" app...

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look here:
[How to retrieve or definitely delete leaderboard in Google Games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591055/how-to-retrieve-or-definitely-delete-leaderboard-in-google-games)

> After removing unnecessary Leaderboards from developer console and Google Services (Settings > Aplication > Google services > clear application data), Google removed all Leaderboards have disappeared. This means that all new users using the application, you will not see the old Leaderboards.

If the described method doesn't solve your issue, go ahead and look here:

[How to remove a Google Play Leaderboard highscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835050/how-to-remove-a-google-play-leaderboard-highscore)

> Answer - you can't. Leaderboards are fixed after publishing and you can't remove entries. I could either hide the dubious score, or, as I did, create a new leaderboard and delete the old.

and follow to the link described in the answer.

I think you may find an answer for your issue in one of the above.
Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i didn't upload my app in google play yet i'm still working in eclipse

Comment: As I mentioned, leaderboards can't be removed. So your best option is to hide particular info on a player, will it satisfy you?

Comment: He does not want to remove a leaderboard entry. He wants to remove the "leaderboards" button from the app.

Comment: Well, probably I missed it from the question.